# prove the following equivalence $\ln(-\frac{l-x+\sqrt{r^2+(l-x)}}{l+x-\sqrt{r^2+(l+x)}})={}$ArcSinh$(\frac{l+x}{r})+{}$ArcSinh$(\frac{l-x}{r})$

Tags: functions, equivalence-relations

Hi guys i'm trying to prove the following equivalence but i'm having some problems:

$$\ln\left(-\frac{\ell-x+\sqrt{r^2+(\ell-x)^{2}}}{\ell+x-\sqrt{r^2+(\ell+x)^{2}}}\right) = \operatorname{ArcSinh} \left(\frac{\ell+x}{r} \right) + \operatorname{ArcSinh} \left(\frac{\ell-x}{r}\right)$$

here all the parameters $\ell$, $x$ and $r$ are real numbers and $\operatorname{ArcSinh}$ is the inverse hyperbolic Sin function.

remind that $\operatorname{ArcSinh}(x)=\ln\left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)$

thanks in advance.

Comment: Divide numerator and denominator by $r$, use an appropriate log property and make use of the fact that arcsine is odd and you'll have the result.

Comment: the problem is that in the denominator there's $l+x-\sqrt{r^{2}+(l+x)}$ I don't know how to get rid of the minus sign

Comment: @user3810266: When $l=x=r=-2$, $LHS=-\ln 2$ and $RHS=\ln (2+\sqrt 5)$.

Comment: unfortunately this is not a proof of the equivalence...

Comment: @Cameron Williams could you please post the steps to obtain the equivalence?

Comment: This is most definitely not a properly posed problem. You should have $-l+x$ in place of $l-x$ in the denominator and you should have squares around the $l+x$ and $l-x$ inside the square roots.

Comment: yeah i forgot to put the squares inside the square root, however the sign in the denominator is correct (note that i don't know how to prove the equivalence i solved an integral with mathematica and i got the LHS while the paper i'm follwing reports the RHS as solution for the integral)